# Stop AngularJS inserting <span class="ng-scope"></span> using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, css-selectors

I'm using the Foundation layout framework, which automatically floats the last sibling of `.column` to the right and I really appreciate this is a behaviour. However, AngularJS takes it upon itself to insert `span.ng-scope` after every `div.column`, which somehow causes browsers to consider the last span the last sibling of `.column` (even though it is not).

Specifically the css in Foundation responsible for this is:

```
[class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child { float: right; }
```

As I understand it, `[attribute*="substring"]` should select only siblings that match, so, for the above, only elements whose class attribute contains `column` (including `columns`). I would think a span tag whose `class` attribute that does not contain `column` should not match (and thus be ignored by `:last-child`). However, this does not seem to be the case.

Regardless, the span *is* causing the problem:

- [Angular buggering it up](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/F5VdG/) (jsfiddle)
- [Works fine without Angular](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/F5VdG/1/) (same jsfiddle, no *ng-include*)

Is there a way to configure angular to stop inserting those `span` tags? I would, begrudgingly, modify the css selector to somehow ignore all span tags; however I might eventually need/want to use a span tag.

Comment: Can `<div class="row">` be moved inside the template?

Comment: Probably (creates a bit of divitis tho)

Comment: The attribute selector should select elements that match, but both the sibling selector and `:last-child` are being interfered with by the `span`s that get auto-inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you indicated the div can be moved inside, this works:

```
<ng-include src="'main.tmpl'"></ng-include>
```

Then in your template:

```
<div class="row">
   <article id="sidepanels" class="four columns">
   ...
</div>
```

I'm not aware of any way to prevent angular from inserting the span tags (I think it keeps track of scopes that way -- for garbage collection).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try my version of include directive that does not creates a scope: [Gist source](https://gist.github.com/4387706).

As no scopes are created, AngularJS should not create additional element to mainain scope (it actually use data attributes to store link to scope).