# is ng-scope inserted only for new scopes?

Tags: angularjs

This may sound kinda dumb .. But I have problems understanding if the 'ng-scope' class is inserted only when a new scope is created, or is it something else ?

Example : I have these lines of code linked to a controller :

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
```

In the web console, both have an ng-scope :

```
<button class="btn ng-scope" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<div ng-show="selected" class="ng-scope ng-binding ng-hide">Selection from a modal: </div>
```

Even when there is no angular-specific data, like here, it will add an ng-scope :

```
<div>hello</div>
```

outputs

```
<div class="ng-scope">hello</div>
```

But why ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any place there is a scope attached.  From [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope):

> Notice that Angular automatically places ng-scope class on elements
>   where scopes are attached. The  definition in this example
>   highlights in red the new scope locations. The child scopes are
>   necessary because the repeater evaluates {{name}} expression, but
>   depending on which scope the expression is evaluated it produces
>   different result.

And in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14166647/781707), @MarkRajcok indicates that angular uses these to track scopes (and garbage collect).

EDIT:
And to answer your edited question. No, this does not add an `ng-scope` class:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4RInd?p=preview) to see this in action.

Notice how `ng-scope` class is only applied to the node where `ng-controller` is declared.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="ng-scope">
  <div>hello2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't explicitly attach a scope to the 2 elements I quoted, or maybe I don't understand well the definition of "scope attached" ?

Comment: Angular will implicitly scope things it knows about (directives) if they are not wrapped in a scope (or `ng-controller`).

Comment: This doesn't help to understand. If I add an element with no angular directive, it will still add a ng-scope : <div>hello</div> will add an ng-scope

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear.  You are using angular directives: `ng-click` and `ng-show`.  All of angular is built on directives (some that we define and some that angular has built in).  Angular first compiles the DOM looking for directives it knows about and then it links scopes to those areas of the page.

Comment: See my edit after you made a change to the question.

Comment: yeah in fact I think it was because my code was directly included with an ng-view, so my guess is that it gave ng-scope to every direct child.

Answer (score -1):

whenever we specify dependency injection at the time of creating angular module

> (angular.module('myApp',**[]**);)

, then only class="ng-class" will get added to 
    `<body ng-app="myApp "ng-controller="myCtrl" class="ng-class">`. If we don't specify DI (angular.module('myApp');) then class="ng-class" will not get added. This is in case of `<body>` element. But except `<body>` element, class="ng-scope" will get added whenever we write ng-controller directive for any html element/tag. Eg. `<div ng-controller="myDiv"></div>`. The output is `<div class="ng-scope"></div>`

Comment: I think this is incorrect: in Angular, calling `angular.module('module')` without a second argument just returns the module.