# Unwanted <span class="ng-scope"> s</span>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I keep on getting an unwanted span tag with and "s" in it when viewing in Chrome. I've searched online but I am still stumped. Help please?

[Stop AngularJS inserting <span class="ng-scope"></span> using ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166420/stop-angularjs-inserting-span-class-ng-scope-span-using-ng-include)

Looked at that post. Similar problem but I think my issue is caused by something else. I am not using ng-include.

Let me know if I can provide more details!

Here is the code https://github.com/benhbaik/crm

Here is public/views/users/all.html and a screenshot of the issue below it.

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>
        Users
        <a href="/users/create" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            New User
        </a>
   </h1>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" ng-show="user.processing">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat spinner"></span>
    <p>Loading Users...</p>
</div>

<!-- GETTING RANDOM SPAN TAG HERE w/ "s" -->

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>Name</th>s
            <th>Username</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in user.users">
            <td>{{ person._id }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.username }}</td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <a href="/users/{{ person._id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" ng-click="user.deleteUser(person._id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is a picture in dev tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05NHs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code:

```
<th>Name</th>s
```

Comment: Oh geez. Thank you sir!